# Is there a way to make this Regex expression less greedy. Using Excel VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have an excel document with a cell with the following information:

```
A) Current to: Notice of 19 June 2014  Sent on: August 2012
B) Updated on: October 2018
C) Updated: 14 January 2009
```

I am using the following regular expression with some success:

```
(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?))\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})
```

the output I have is as follows:

```
A) 19 June2014August2012
B) October 2018
C) 14 January 2009
```

B and C extract fine, however I am expecting 19 June 2014 for A

I have tried adding .*? to make the expression less greedy, but (depending where I add the dot-star), I either get no result or I get an inaccurate response

Comment: This has nothing to do with greediness. Do you want to extract the first date on a line? If yes, use `regEx.Multiline = True` and then `^.*?((?:\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(?:\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?(?:(?:19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2}))` pattern and then access `match.Submatches(0)`

Comment: this worked like a charm! thank you very much. if you want to add this as a solution, I will mark it as correct - I can't mark your comment as an answer

Comment: All you really need to do is set `.global = False`  It will stop after returning the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the first match on a line you may add `^.*?` at the beginning of the pattern, wrap what you have with capturing parentheses and set the `Multiline` regex property to `True`. Your match is inside `match.Submatches(0)`.

```
regEx.Pattern = "^.*?((?:\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(?:\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?(?:(?:19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2}))"
regEx.Multiline = True
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3HYtEa/1).